# In/on prepositions when referring to a front or back-end (computing)

Tags: prepositions, technical, computing

When writing about computing, should I refer to a component `in the front-end` or `on the front-end`? For example:

> It was decided to place the function **in** the front-end

Or should it be

> It was decided to place the function **on** the front-end

Is it the same preposition for the back-end?

I will appreciate any help with this, as grammar-checking websites consider both sentences correct, and I see many instances of both `in` and `on` the front/back-end on books.google.com/ngrams.

Comment: Depends on where you're placing it.  Are you placing it in the box labeled "front end", or attaching it to the front of another box?

Comment: @HotLicks, the front-end in this case is a program that presents to a user a set of functions to control some hardware, and hides the details about how to actually use the hardware. All these details are contained in the back-end. I think the function in this example is inside a box labeled "front-end"; however, this box is placed in front of the "back-end" box.

Comment: I was a computer programmer for over 40 years.

Comment: @HotLicks, sorry if I sound like I'm oversimplifying, I'm just trying to make the example as general as possible.

Comment: If you have a box labeled "front end", and you are placing it in that box, then it's "**in** the front end".  If you have a single large box and you are appending on the front of that box then it's "**on** the front end".

Comment: @HotLicks, thank you, that makes it very easy to understand.

Comment: It is absolultely nothing to do with grammar. There are two competing metaphors.

Comment: It was decided to make the function a part of the front-end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at some examples of the phrases ["in the backend"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+the+backend%22&biw=1680&bih=948&source=lnt&tbs=sbd%3A1%2Cbkt%3Ab%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1990%2Ccd_max%3A&tbm=bks) and ["on the backend"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on+the+backend%22&biw=1680&bih=948&source=lnt&tbs=sbd%3A1%2Cbkt%3Ab%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1990%2Ccd_max%3A&tbm=bks) on Google Books, it seems that anything that runs in the backend (processes, services, etc.) you put in the backend. You use **on**, for example, when you install something on the backend. When referring to work, you work **on** the backend, or work is done **on** the backend.

Some examples I found:

- [we tried using an embedded http server **in** the backend](https://books.google.se/books?id=Q002_TiMJ6kC&pg=PA706&dq=%22in+the+backend%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy8770-MjiAhXRwcQBHSX9CMkQ6AEINDAC)
- [since dependence analysis **in** the backend is usually less accurate than **in** the frontend](https://books.google.se/books?id=mgdrCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA216&dq=%22in+the+backend%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy8770-MjiAhXRwcQBHSX9CMkQ6AEIPjAE)
- [The processing of a query is carried out entirely **in** the backend](https://books.google.se/books?id=uT4kAQAAIAAJ&q=%22in+the+backend%22&dq=%22in+the+backend%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy8770-MjiAhXRwcQBHSX9CMkQ6AEITzAI)
- [Installing DRBD **on** the backend servers](https://books.google.se/books?id=jeXuBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA217&dq=%22on+the+backend%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1g8nn-MjiAhVuwMQBHf3ZB8YQ6AEILzAB)
- [Work **on** the backend translators will involve some extra overhead](https://books.google.se/books?id=6BEiAQAAIAAJ&q=%22on+the+backend%22&dq=%22on+the+backend%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1g8nn-MjiAhVuwMQBHf3ZB8YQ6AEIQzAF)

Comment: *Back end* is sometimes used in relation to business functions that take place  *in the back office*.  If the term *office* fits naturally into your exposition in place of *end*, then *in* will probably sound natural as a preposition.